# VS Code "Cannot find module" error on Firebase Functions Project

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code

I set up a firebase functions project on visual studio code and inside the index.ts file I was unable to make it recognize the imported modules. The autocomplete shows that the modules exist, however when I import them I get the error "Cannot find module".

But the project compiles and passes the lint check. I just cannot use the intellisense. I tested the solutions below but cannot get it working;

- Remove node-modules folder then execute `npm install`.
- Create new firebase functions project on a new directory.
- Uninstall and reinstall vs-code. (Removing every property inside AppData).
- Reinstall the typescript globally.
- Remove extensions.
- Test on MacOS instead of Windows 10

**Screenshots**

- The error

  [image]
- Folder structure

  [image]
- tsconfig.json

  ```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "commonjs",
       "noImplicitReturns": true,
       "noUnusedLocals": true,
       "outDir": "lib",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "strict": true,
       "target": "es2017",
       "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"] 
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": ["src", "decs.d.ts"]
  }
  ```
- package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^4.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-multipart-file-parser": "^0.1.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using images in your question unless *necessary*, for more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my use case.

in JS

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
```

in TS

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/analytics"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/storage"
```

in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    ...
  },
```

You can find official doc about ES2015 style import in the firebase document page
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

ps. A screenshot is really helpful to describe your problem in general. Don't be care

Comment: Although I like this approach, unfortunately the issue still persists. I highly suspect that it is an issue with VS Code.

Comment: It could be solved without any VSCode IDE side solution. Could you check if you installed firebase? not only 'firebase-admin' and 'firebase-auth' the specific parts modules. As long as you follow the documentation, you need to execute this ```npm install --save firebase```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work either. I guess it conflicts with something else.